# How do I reset my Session id?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I am trying to destroy a session after he makes successful payment .

```
 $session_id = session_id();

    $sql = "
        UPDATE
            tbl_seat_book
        SET
            final_book = 'Y'
        WHERE
            session_id = '$session_id'
    ";
    $r = $this->db->executeQuery($sql);

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

    echo 'Booking successfull';
```

But when I book tickets , the same `session_id` appears . How can I destroy the `session_id` after making successful payment .

EDIT :

```
$sql = "
        INSERT INTO
            tbl_seat_book
        SET
            booking_date = '$_REQUEST[bus_date]',
            booking_time = '$_REQUEST[bus_time]',
            bus_id = '$_REQUEST[bus_id]',
            route_id = '$_REQUEST[route_id]',
            session_id = '$session_id',
            session_start_time = '$time',
            temp_book = 'Y',
            final_book = 'N',
            $cond
    ";
    $booked = $this->db->insertQuery($sql);
```

EDIT2:

```
function book_final_tickets()
{

    $session_id = session_id();
    $sql = "
        UPDATE
            tbl_seat_book
        SET
            final_book = 'Y'
        WHERE
            session_id = '$session_id'
    ";


    //session_unset();

    if($r = $this->db->executeQuery($sql)){
        if(session_destroy()){
            unset($session_id); 
            echo 'Booking successfull';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/session_destroy

Answer (score 5):

Use [`session_regenerate_id(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) to generate a new session ID and delete the old one. Note that this will keep all of the information in `$_SESSION` as part of the new session ID.

e.g. **To get a new session ID, but keep session info in `$_SESSION`.**

```
// Regenerate session ID, user gets a new sid, and cookie is updated.
session_regenerate_id(true);

// Make sure you pick up the new session ID
$session_id = session_id();

// Note, $_SESSION will be the same here as before, but $session_id will be diff.
// Old session info has been moved to new session.
```

If you don't want to keep the information in `$_SESSION` either, then you want to use [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to destroy the session info on the server-side, and [`setcookie()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to manually unset the session ID cookie on the client-side. Then you can start a new session and generate a new session ID as before.

e.g. **To get a new session_id AND remove all session information.**

```
session_unset();   // Remove the $_SESSION variable information.
session_destroy(); // Remove the server-side session information.

// Unset the cookie on the client-side.
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", 1); // Force the cookie to expire.

// Start a new session
session_start();

// Generate a new session ID
session_regenerate_id(true);

// Then finally, make sure you pick up the new session ID
$session_id = session_id();

// $_SESSION will now be empty, and $session_id will have been regenerated.
// You have a completely empty, new session.
```

*(You can get away without the `setcookie()` call here, since you're creating a new session anyway, so the cookie will be overwritten by the new ID, but it's good practice to explicitly destroy the old cookie).*

---

`session_destroy()` alone won't remove the client-side cookie, so the next time the user visits, they'll still have the same session id set (but their server-side session info will have been destroyed).

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. ... In order to kill the
>   session altogether, like to log the user out, **the session id must also
>   be unset**. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default
>   behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Your Just replace session_unset() with session_destroy()

```
$session_id = session_id();

$sql = "
    UPDATE
        tbl_seat_book
    SET
        final_book = 'Y'
    WHERE
        session_id = '$session_id'
";
if($this->db->executeQuery($sql))
{
    session_destroy();
    echo 'Booking successfull';
}
```

Comment: please see my update.Also, in http://7sisters.in/7sislabs/ you can see that the session_id is not changing,after successful ticket book. I have echoed the session_id to test .

Answer (score 1):

session_unset(); only free the variable that you have registered, if you want to destroy all session the use `session_destroy();`

Comment: I have updated with session_unset();session_destroy(); but showing same result ! its not get destroyed

Comment: how you check for the session

Comment: After booking is successful,I tried making new ticket with session_id,in which session_id is same as previous one .

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
session_unset(); //destroys variables
session_destroy(); //destroys session
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['req_value']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['req_value']);   
}
```